# Dismissible in flutter shouldn't dismiss item in case of error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Below code works fine unless there is an error. Even in case of an error like 'no network' or 'cannot connect to database', the item is dismissed from the list when its shouldn't be deleted. How to handle this in case of errors?

```
class DismissibleListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const DismissibleListItem({
    this.key,
    this.product,
    this.onTap,
  });

  final Key key;
  final Product product;
  final VoidCallback onDismissed;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      background: Container(color: Colors.red),
      key: key,
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      onDismissed: (direction) => onDismissed(),
      child: ProductListItem(
        product: product,
        onTap: onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dismissible` Widget has an option for this, `confirmDismiss`. It expects a `Future<bool>`. You give it a `Future` method that returns a `true` or `false`. So depending if your network operation fails, or doesn't, you can make the `Dismissible` reset:

```
class Issue65842845 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Issue65842845State createState() => _Issue65842845State();
}

class _Issue65842845State extends State<Issue65842845> {
  List<String> items = [
    'item 1',
    'item 2',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return Dismissible(
          background: Container(color: Colors.red),
          key: Key(items[index].hashCode.toString()),
          direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
          confirmDismiss: (direction) => confirmDismiss(items[index]),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
            child: Text(items[index]),
            height: 30,
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<bool> confirmDismiss(String text) async {
    if(text == 'item 1'){
      // Operation was successful and item was removed from remote server
      // Dismissible is removed
      return true;
    } else {
      // Operation failed and Dismissible is reset
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @RameshKumar I'm glad I could help you with a solution. Please consider up-voting the answer for added visibility

Comment: Did but got this message. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Makes sense. Good luck with your app!

Comment: What if the confirmDismiss is used for the dialog confirmation? How to handle failure in delete then (which is executed by `onDismissed`)?

Comment: @a7md0 use onUpdate to handle the alert dialog, since it's called before onDismissed. If checks are successful , then onDismissed can take over. For instance, I used onUpdate to check internet connection prior to dismissing any widgets.